# Avaje Ebean compoundType

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using play!framework 2.

I am trying to write an EBean compound type.

I wrote something like

```
public class A implements CompoundType<A>{
 .... implemented all the methods.. 
}
```

etc..

Then I tried to use it

```
@Entity
public class B extends Model{

    public A a;

}
```

When I dump the DDL I cannot seem to find a reference to "a" on table "b".

What am I doing wrong?

#### EDIT

Actually, I have no idea what to expect or how the column definition occurs. The `CompoundType` interface has `getProperties` method - which returns an array of `CompoundTypeProperty`. The property API has `getName`. So I assume that EBean invokes this method on configuration phase to understand which columns my compound type exposes.

I expect these columns to be embedded (without annotation) to the declaring class. 
However, I am not clear how this works combined with `@Column` annotation. So I am probably missing out on something..

Any clarification will be helpful as documentation is awfully poor on this.

Comment: You may have forgotten the `@Column` annotation under the A property in your B class, no ?

Comment: Tried adding "Column" - it had no effect.